# Falta traducción al no encontrar resultados en una búsqueda

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones, traducida-falta-revisar

Cuando buscas y no encuentras resultados ([ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=bla%20ble%20bli)) arroja tres sugerencias, la primera sigue estando en inglés

> Try fewer keywords

Como se ve en la imagen:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Está en Transifex: [Try fewer keywords](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/136903025?key=f217af64b69e437f7667430fac197e0b)

Comment: En [Try fewer keywords](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/136903025?key=f217af64b69e437f7667430fac197e0b) se sugiere _Prueba menos palabras clave_. He puesto otra sugerencia: _Intenta con menos palabras clave_, para mantener el estilo de las otras dos sugerencias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Propuse la traducción](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-es/translate/#es/english/136903025?key=f217af64b69e437f7667430fac197e0b) en Transifex, g3rv4 la aprobó, se hizo un pull de la base de datos... y ya se ve bien ([ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=bla%20ble%20bli)):

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ves, ahora dice:

> Intenta con menos palabras clave.

Comment: ?search=bla%ble%bli

Comment: Esperemos que nadie publique una pregunta con `bla` `ble` `bli`, para que el ejemplo siga valiendo :-P